# using while loop has problems in this code

Tags: c++

In this all the code is correct, except the fact that the while loop doesn’t work, if and else conditions are OK but the while loop doesn’t function, please help!

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int interval=0;
    int total;   
    cout<<"Enter a number = ";
    cin>>total;

    while(interval!=-1) {
        if (total % 10 == 0) {
            total=total-10;
            total=total/5;
            cout<<"total= "<< total<<endl;

            cout<<"1st number= "<<total<<endl;
            cout<<"2nd number= "<<total+1<<endl;
            cout<<"3rd number= "<<total+2<<endl;
            cout<<"4th number= "<<total+3<<endl;
            cout<<"5th number= "<<total+4<<endl;    
        } else {
            cout<<"re-enter the number"<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think once it enter into the else condition,it will stuck here because you are taking number in if condition so it will not get any chance to go back into if condition because if condition become always false.

Comment: `Interval` never changes which is the loop isn't functioning the way you want it to.

Comment: so whats the solution?

Comment: Everything that is wrong with Stack Overflow can be summed up by this comment from the poster on an answer:  
`can you please correct my code and send it to me? –  user3152720`.

Answer (score 2):

This program will result an infinite loop because `interval` value didn't change

```
while(interval!=-1) 
{

  // you should change interval value so the loop will end
}
```

Comment: can you please correct the code and post bcz i am new to programming so i am not understanding what you are saying

Comment: What your program try to do?

Comment: i am trying to process all the above when if is applied or else, but i want that all to be continous such that if i end up with if or else, the programme should again ask for input

Answer (score 1):

You never change `interval` in the loop, so it never ends.

Answer (score 1):

I think once it enter into the else condition,it will stuck here because you are taking number in if condition so it will not get any chance to go back into if condition because if condition become always false.

Answer (score 0):

You set `interval` to `0` and then loop until it's `-1` but *you never change its value* within the loop.

Comment: @user3152720: no. For one, I have no idea what your code is supposed to do. Secondly, this isn't rent-a-coder: we're here to help, not do your work for you. I would suggest trying to fix it yourself given the information, then posting your attempt and a more specific question for further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to remain in the while loop *till* you get a proper number. So instead of using that variable *interval*, just do this:

```
while(1)//Make it infinite loop 
{

if (total % 10 == 0)
{

total=total-10;
total=total/5;
cout<<"total= "<< total<<endl;

cout<<"1st number= "<<total<<endl;
cout<<"2nd number= "<<total+1<<endl;
cout<<"3rd number= "<<total+2<<endl;
cout<<"4th number= "<<total+3<<endl;
cout<<"5th number= "<<total+4<<endl;    
break; //Break out of the loop on receiving the correct number and on performing and printing the calculations
}
else 
{
 cout<<"re-enter the number"<<endl;
}

}
```

Hope this works for you!!

Comment: no it didn't an infinity loop is there and secondly my main thing is that i want that suppose 'else' is implimented and then i want that it should retake the value

Comment: that infinity loop is there because it will allow you to retake the number *till* you get the right value. It will continue executing till you type in the right value. Then it breaks out of the loop after performing the calculations. I am telling you to use infinity loop so that you dont have to use a variable like *interval* to track when to break out of the loop. This will work for your case.

Comment: It will behave like infinite loop *only until* the execution enters the if condition of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler will optimize this as **interval** is not changed anywhere inside whileloop and as well you have not mention **interval** as volatile. 
Use step by step debugging to agree to my point.
Solution : change interval inside the while loop.